# Can an Argument be ever a hypothesis?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-language, validity

Can I have an argument which can be a hypothesis?

Comment: This needs to be more specific.  What do you mean by "hypothesis" here?  Do you have some specific context in mind?  Maybe an example of a case in which an argument might be a hypothesis, but you're not certain?

Comment: Sally seems to be sick because she has hand on her forehead. This is an argument but does it include hypothesis?

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean by "includes a hypothesis."  In your example, someone could take the conclusion of the argument (Sally is sick) and treat it as a hypothesis for further investigation (using a thermometer to see whether she has a fever, for example).

Answer (score 1):

An [argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument) :

> is [a set] of *premises* (typically in the form of propositions, statements or sentences) in support of a claim: the *conclusion*.

A *deductive* argument asserts that the truth of the conclusion is a logical consequence of the premises.

An *inductive* argument, on the other hand, asserts that the truth of the conclusion is supported to some degree of probability by the premises.

When you speak of [hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothesis) are you considering the use of the term in the context scientific explanation, where a hypothesis is a proposed explanation for a phenomenon, or in the context of formal logic, where the term denotes the antecedent of a conditional proposition "if ---,then ___" ?

If we consider formal logic, we may use an hypothesis as a premise in an argument; in this case, we say that, "assuming" e.g. **A**, in conjunction with a second premise **A → B**, we may infer the conclusion **B** by way of the deductive argument form called *modus ponens*.

In this case, the hypothesis is part of the argument.